Conditionally Formatting a Grid in Excel
I have a table that I'm using to check if both sides of a transaction balance which works like so:



Companies
A-Corp
Bee Ltd
Cee Inc




A-Corp
XXX
-10,000
-50,000


Bee Ltd
10,000
XXX
0


Cee Inc
47,000
0
XXX



The first column are the companies who owe money, the header row are who the money is owed to.
A-Corp think they are owed 10,000 by Bee Ltd and 50,000 by Cee Inc
Bee Ltd agree that they owe 10,000 to A-Corp
Cee Inc think they only owe A-Corp 47,000
Is there any easy way to highlight matching sets of figures?
The only way I can think of is using conditional formatting formulae like this:
=$B$3=(0-$C$2) applying to =$B$3,$C$2
=$B$4=(0-$D$2) applying to =$B$4,$D$2 etc.
But given the size of the table I'm using that would require 169 individual rules so I'm hoping there's a more efficient way of doing it.

The task is to build a formula that answers this question:

Does the value in the current cell with row header R and column header C match the value in the cell with row header C and column header R?

As a grid formula:
=LET(
currentCell,C3,
colHeader,C$2,
rowHeader,$B3,
currentCell+INDEX($C$3:$E$5,XMATCH(colHeader,$B$3:$B$5),XMATCH(rowHeader,$C$2:$E$2))=0
)

Which is of course equivalent to this shorter but perhaps less readable formula:
=C3+INDEX($C$3:$E$5,XMATCH(C$2,$B$3:$B$5),XMATCH($B3,$C$2:$E$2))=0


And applied as a single conditional formatting rule:

If you then want to highlight the mismatches in some other colour, you can add a second rule and change the equality operator in the last line from = to the inequality operator <>.

Here is a very roughly sketched out solution: you essentially just need to inverse rows and columns. You could do that through INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...)) [I'm not sure if the latest version of Excel allows formulae inside RC notation yet].
TopLeftCell = INDEX(array, COL()-offsety, ROW()-offsetx)

Where offsety and offsetx are the ROW and COLUMN of the top left hand corner of your cell.

what is offsety and offsetx? Your post doesn't look like a complete solution. Please only post answers which fully solve the problem and share hints in comments instead.

"both sides of a transaction" really doesn't make sense.
For the 3 entities ("companies") that you've shown, there are two separate payment/receipt expectations, each involving one 'sender' and one 'receiver'. How do you plan to accommodate one on-going, disputed 'transaction' between two entities when a second undisputed one arises? Do you have to manually zero-out "settled" transactions??
I wouldn't want to be responsible for updating values in this 13x13 table.

The problem "has the feel of" a very simple 'Crystal Ball' workbook I developed years ago. Its purpose was to peer into the future observing the balances of several bank accounts (and several mortgages) covering several months.
Quite simply, one sheet - the balance tracker - had its column A auto-filled with future dates (3-4 months was ample) from 'yesterday', then one column for each account (or mortgage) being tracked. This was just a mass of sumif() formulas that totalled zero-or-more cells from the second sheet (selected by matching dates), then adding that signed sum to the previous day's closing balance to find the current day's closing balance.
The second sheet was for future 'transactions'. Its column A was also filled with a date for each anticipated future transaction. A few more columns provided some "human" understanding of the purpose of each transaction. Then, further to the right, were the same columns of accounts and mortgages as on the first sheet. A negative dollar value would be entered into the column of one of the bank accounts, and the same value as a positive amount entered into one of the mortgage account columns.
Adapting the concept to your situation, I would enter a row on the second sheet (some future date) with its details, debiting an amount from the appropriate bank account and crediting it to the applicable mortgage account. NB: In my case, all of these "money in motion" transfers used the same value for each side of the transaction. Transactions listed on the second sheet allowed me to monitor account balances on the first sheet avoiding both "account overdrawn" and/or "late payment" penalties for a forgotten payment. Official statements listed historical transactions, as did my workbook. Its "crystal ball" powers of forecasting future balances enabled better short term use of available cash.
Aside: One sided deposits or withdrawals (income from outside sources and payments to outside debtors) made up the most of my workbook's transactions. The OP seems to deal only with 13 known 'sources and sinks' for transactions to be monitored.

This story is offered for the OP to reconsider using a single sheet to track and detect what appear to be possibly 'unbalanced' sides of multiple (pending?) (unrelated?) transactions between multiple entities.
Given a bit more thought, the simplistic formatting of "red digits for non-zero values" in the "overview" sheet might obviate the need for the complexities of "conditional formatting". (Perhaps even use the program's ability to "suppress display of zero values (balanced transactions)" would be better to show only those activities that need further attention.)

Answers are intended to provide solution for the problem. Explaining why the whole setup is wrong should be done in a comment - in a much shorter version.

@MátéJuhász Thank you for your reaction. Please link to the applicable community user guide where I may acquaint myself with details such as this.

@MátéJuhász By coincidence, this answer surfaced a few moments ago, albeit in a quite different "community"... My philosophy is to try to assist one who has gotten off on the wrong foot, not merely snipe at their taste in shoes...

"What is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or at least a viable alternative. Your answer can say “don’t do that,” but it should also say “try this instead.”" in https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer. Although I see you explain alternative solution, however even reading it multiple times and even agreeing with your proposal it's still difficult for me to follow your argumentation. Overall I can't see anything definitely wrong with your answer, however neither I can say it's a good one. Either is should be more concise, or should have some pictures for suppport.

@MátéJuhász Thank you for your response. Some like concision; some (esp. beginners) prefer repetition. If the OP should see this answer and have questions, I'll do my best to expand on any particulars. (OT: "Transaction Matching/Pairing" was a fair description of my tenure with a nation's 'Central Bank', monitoring and ensuring liquidity of financial players in real time... That was a bit more than an XLS... I'm writing with some relevant experience, though.)
